# Xamarin apk signed install location

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, android-install-apk

I have a Single-View app made in Xamarin, with Visual Studio 2017.
If I run the app from Visual Studio in Debug mode, the app gets installed in sdcard/Android/data/...

If I build on release and sign the apk Ad-Hoc(the use adk to install), or run on release directly, the app gets installed, but I am unable to find where. Apparently it is in a secure hidden location on the device, where I have no access.

Is there something special I need to do to have an apk that can be installed and deployed in Android/data/.. ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case if it still actual for someone else. Keep attention on two things:
Android Manifest option Install location: Prefer External
Android option: Use Fast Deployment - disabled.